# How to remove top comment lines with sed?

Tags: sed

I know how to delete all comments or delete specified row in file, but don't know how to delete only first top comment lines that hold author, copyright and etc. I can't just use delete first lines because there might be source files that does not con taint top comment block at all. Any suggestion?

**UPDATE**: The source files are objective-c files, and all top comment lines start with `//`. Probably the rule "delete all comment lines until first non-comment line will be found then stop" best describes what I would like to achieve.

**Second question:** Also, looking for a way to tell sed to loop recursively though all project directories and files.

**UPDATE2**. Here's an example of the comment block of objective-c file I'm trying to modify:

```
//
//  MyProjectAppDelegate.m
//  MyProject
//
//  Created by Name Surname on 2011-09-20.
//  Copyright 2012 JSC MyCompany. All rights reserved.
//
```

Comment: Define what 'first' means: until a non-comment line? What kind of comments? C, shell, SQL, ...?

Comment: Use `find` to find all files in a directory tree.

Answer (score 2):

if awk is accepted as well, take a look at following:

```
 awk 'BEGIN{f=1}f&&/^\/\//{next;}{f=0}1' yourFile
```

**test**

```
kent$  cat test.txt
//
//  MyProjectAppDelegate.m
//  MyProject
//
//  Created by Name Surname on 2011-09-20.
//  Copyright 2012 JSC MyCompany. All rights reserved.
//
real codes come here...

// comments in codes should be kept

foo bar foo bar


kent$  awk 'BEGIN{f=1}f&&/^\/\//{next;}{f=0}1' test.txt
real codes come here...

// comments in codes should be kept

foo bar foo bar
```

you could combine find and the awk one-liner to do a recursive processing.

well sed can do that with same idea too. need to write a mark in Hold space, and check hold space for every line. It has an advantage with -i option, which allows you change your original file(s). however I feel awk is more straightforward to do the job. And saving changed text back to original file is not a hard thing either.

Comment: Don't be afraid of whitespace, this isn't golf: `awk -v f=1 {f && /^\/\// {next} {f=0; print}' yourFile`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `sed` solution that works with *Kent's* `test.txt`:

```
sed -n '/^ *\/\//! { :a;p;N;s/.*\n//;ba}'
```

Output:

```
real codes come here...

// comments in codes should be kept

foo bar foo bar
```

*Explanation*

```
sed -n '/^ *\/\//!{    # if line does not start with //
  :a                   # label a
  p                    # print line
  N                    # append next line to PS
  s/.*\n//             # remove previous line
  ba                   # branch to a
}' < test.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

try it:

```
sed '0,\#^\([^/]\|/[^/]\)\|^$# d'
```